# How can I prevent multiple executions of the MDC clear method in Apache Camel 3 logging in my SpringBoot app?

Tags: spring-boot, logging, apache-camel, mdc

I am using Apache Camel's MDC logging functionality to log custom fields within a SpringBoot application through a Custom UnitOfWork. Since upgrade to Camel 3 I am experiencing unexpected multiple executions of MDC clear method for the single message processing. As consequence of that, incomplete logs are generated. I am struggling in understanding what triggers the clear execution.

I added custom logs to Camel 2 based application to understand how it worked before: clear method was only executed at the end of the route.